# How to return the value of a pointer in a list?

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers, vector

I've got a "Faction" class, and a vector of pointers which I want to turn into a list. This is the method for it. I assume I've managed to turn the vector of pointers into a list alright in the first part, so now I want to print the list out within my method. I know by using the '*', I'm printing out the memory location as opposed to the value, and that's exactly what this code is doing.

```
list<Faction*> Faction::linklistFactions() {
    list<Faction*> list_factions(factionptr_.begin(), factionptr_.end());
    cout << "printing linked list:" << endl;

   for (int a = 0; a < list_factions.size(); a++)
   {
      std::list<Faction*>::iterator i = list_factions.begin();
      advance(i, a);
      cout << *i;
      cout << ",";
   }

   return list_factions;
}
```

But I want to print out the value, not the memory location. So instead of

```
cout << *i;
```

I can do something like

```
cout << i->getFactionname();
```

I am already able to do this for my vector, it was simple enough:

```
string Faction::getFactionname() const
{
     return factionname_;
}
```

But I'm having trouble coming up with a similar method for my list. It doesn't work the same, and I'm not sure why. Perhaps there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your iteration is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)` (because `advance()` on a `list::iterator` will have to call `++` `a` times - it's a linear-time operation). The proper way in C++03 to iterate through a list is to use iterators:

```
for (std::list<Faction*>::iterator i = list_factions.begin(); 
     i != list_factions.end(); ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

Which in C++11 reduces to:

```
for (Faction* i : list_factions) { ... }
```

Secondly, `i` "points" to a `Faction*`: `*i` is a `Faction*`, which means if you want to call `Faction` member functions, you have to additionally dereference it:

```
std::cout << (*i)->getFactionName() << std::endl;
```

Lastly, unless you're really really sure you need a `list`, stick with `vector`.